# how to call eway payment gateway form on different location

Tags: php, wordpress, payment-gateway, eway

I have install woocommerce in my wordpress application and also install eway payment gateway plugin. it is showing perfect on my default checkout page.
But i want to call it on different location ( i have donation page in my application and want to use eway there as well) as I am new to wordpress got stuck very badly.

please give me suggestion whatever possible and ask me for code if you want any.

Comment: Depending on your needs, the [eWAY Pay Now button](https://www.eway.com.au/features/payments-pay-now) is a very simple integration as it is only a piece of JavaScript that can be added to a page. The disadvantage is that it won't hook into WooCommerce orders.

Comment: @JohnC does it allow me store payment details in database like storing user name ,amount?

Comment: You would need to do some additional work to request the transaction results and save the response. It is really designed to work as a fast drop in solution, which limits customisation options.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't use eway payment gateway without e-commerce plugin. Which means you need product :), and you can't consider a donation as a product at all. I am sure that you have installed the plugin for Woocommerce only. To integrate eway on donation page you need to use eway API. here is the reference for the same. 
https://www.eway.com.au/developers/api